# Placing a CSS transparent overlay over image AND making a JavaScript function work when image is clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, css, onclick, overlay

I'm having trouble with scripting my CSS in such a way that it will let me do the following at the **same time**:

- clear the colored overlay (red) when I hover over the
- make my picture clickable so that it will perform an unrelated JavaScript function

Currently I can only do only one of these things separately at a time.

My first attempt - clearing the colored overlay on hover BUT my JavaScript function will not work:

```js
function myFunction() {
 /..../
}
```

```css
.image {
    position:relative;
    width:400px;
    height:400px;
}

.image:after {
    content:'\A';
    position:absolute;
    width:100%; height:100%;
    top:0; left:0;
    background:rgba(256,0,0,0.6);
    opacity:1;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
}
.image:hover:after {
    opacity:0;
}

.cursor { cursor: pointer}

.myImage {
  background: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sjsbh.jpg") no-repeat 50% 50%;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="image">
<!--when the "image" class is present, I cannot perform myFunction() by clicking on the picture -->

  <div class="myImage cursor" onclick="myFunction()">
  
  </div>
</div>http://jsfiddle.net/9z26ky19/2429/#run
```

My alternate attempt - here my JavaScript function works BUT I no longer have a colored (red) overlay since I got rid of the "image" class:

```js
function myFunction() {
 /..../
}
```

```css
.image {
    position:relative;
    width:400px;
    height:400px;
}

.image:after {
    content:'\A';
    position:absolute;
    width:100%; height:100%;
    top:0; left:0;
    background:rgba(256,0,0,0.6);
    opacity:1;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
}
.image:hover:after {
    opacity:0;
}

.cursor { cursor: pointer}

.myImage {
  background: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sjsbh.jpg") no-repeat 50% 50%;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div>
<!--when the "image" class is NOT present, myFunction() JavaScript works BUT I no longer have the colored (red) overlay -->

  <div class="myImage cursor" onclick="myFunction()">
  
  </div>
</div>http://jsfiddle.net/9z26ky19/2429/#run
```

How can I script it in a way such that I can have both a colored (red) overlay over my image AND have my JavaScript myFunction work?

Comment: One way I found to do it is by putting `display:none` on `image:hover:after` but I lose the opacity transition effect and it ends up not being very elegant in action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about simply moving the click handler to the parent `.image` `<div>`?

```js
function myFunction() {
 console.log('clicked');
}
```

```css
.image {
    position:relative;
    width:400px;
    height:400px;
}

.image:after {
    content:'\A';
    position:absolute;
    width:100%; height:100%;
    top:0; left:0;
    background:rgba(256,0,0,0.6);
    opacity:1;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
}
.image:hover:after {
    opacity:0;
}

.cursor { cursor: pointer}

.myImage {
  background: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sjsbh.jpg") no-repeat 50% 50%;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="image" onclick="myFunction()">
  <div class="myImage cursor">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I didn't think of that.  Elegant simple solution.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`pointer-events: none;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) on the `:after` pseudo element to make it transparent to mouse events:

```js
function myFunction() {
  console.log('click');
}
```

```css
.image {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
}

.image:after {
  content: '\A';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(256, 0, 0, 0.6);
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.image:hover:after {
  opacity: 0;
}

.cursor {
  cursor: pointer
}

.myImage {
  background: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sjsbh.jpg") no-repeat 50% 50%;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="image">
  <!--when the "image" class is present, I cannot perform myFunction() by clicking on the picture -->

  <div class="myImage cursor" onclick="myFunction()">

  </div>
</div>http://jsfiddle.net/9z26ky19/2429/#run
```